# Make Image with Text Function Not Working

Tags: php, image, text

I'm trying to create some images with text on them.  Here is the function I have created:

```
function makeTitleImage($text){
  $im = imagecreatetruecolor(160,160);
  $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im,154,205,50);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
  imagefill($im,0,0,$background_color);
  imagettftext($im,10,0,0,$text_color,"./ASansBlack.ttf",$text);
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  imagepng($im,($text.'.jpg'));
  imagedestroy($im);
}
```

This creates a 160x160px image with the background colour but no text, named appropriately (so I know `$text` is being passed in correctly).  The path to the `.ttf` file is accurate.  Not sure what else could be going on?  Probably something silly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imagettftext` function is missing a parameter, which is the y-coordinate of the text. Try something like

```
imagettftext($im,10,0,0,10,$text_color,"./ASansBlack.ttf",$text);
```

Comment: Ah, see, I knew it was going to be something silly.  Thank you very much!